# Working with shortcuts (ReleaseComObject?)

Tags: powershell, com

I have to mass-change shortcuts (.lnk) with PowerShell in an enterprise environment.
Users maybe have wrong shortcuts on their desktop. The desktop folder is located on our central storage. I need to correct them, if the shortcuts have wrong arguments. I am talking about 5.000 users.

My code is ready and working fine. It is based on some examples I found on Google.

In some examples I did see something like:

```
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ShortcutObject)
```

I don't know what this is for?

Broken down the relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
$UserShortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Path "MyFolder" -ChildPath "SmithJ\Desktop") -Filter *.lnk |
                 Where-Object Name -Match "MyShortcut"

foreach ($UserShortcut in $UserShortcuts) {
    $sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $ShortcutObject = $sh.CreateShortcut($($UserShortcut.FullName))

    $ShortcutObject.Arguments
    # ...
}
```

What about the `ReleaseComObject()`?
Do I have to do this after every object?
It is working without. Do I have to use it?

**EDIT:**
With the information of Bill_Stewart I think it would be correct like this:

```
$UserShortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Path "MyFolder" -ChildPath "SmithJ\Desktop") -Filter *.lnk |
                 Where-Object Name -Match "MyShortcut"

$sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

foreach ($UserShortcut in $UserShortcuts) {
    $ShortcutObject = $sh.CreateShortcut($($UserShortcut.FullName))
    $ShortcutObject.Arguments
    # ...
}

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sh)
```

Comment: it means release the object/process from the memory, cleanup job..., not always working though, you sometimes need to kill the process anyway

Comment: Yes, you need to include it every time you're using a `com` object to release the resources and avoid memory leaks.

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: This means, that the ReleaseComObject-Line should be placed inside the loop in my example above. correct?  
Foreach-Object ...

Comment: You don't need to create a new instance of the `WshShell` (progid `WScript.Shell`) inside your loop. You only need to create it once outside the `foreach` loop and reuse it inside the loop.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That is a good point. I thought about it while coding, but I wasn't sure. Thank you.
I did make an edit on my question with updated code. Would it be correct like this?

Comment: I doubt that the `WshShell` object needs to be released (it's common not to do so in WSH scripts), but it won't hurt anything to do so.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx):

> Therefore, use the [*sic*] ReleaseComObject only if it is absolutely required.

Implicit in this sentence is that you have an understanding of the technical details of how managed code (in this case, PowerShell, which uses .NET) uses COM objects.

For PowerShell scripts calling scripting runtime COM objects (such as `WshShell`, `WshShortcut`, `WshUrlShortcut`, etc.), there is no need to use `ReleaseComObject` as the .NET runtime (CLR) will automatically release them when they are no longer in use.

This is not necessarily the case with all COM objects when automated from PowerShell, but for scripting runtime objects releasing is unnecessary.